# i cannot access Zend_Auth::getInstance () after login in linux plateform

Tags: zend-framework

### i cannot access Zend_Auth::getInstance () after login in linux platform while its working fine in windows platform.

in login page:-

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance ();
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable ();
$authAdapter->setIdentity ('Sameer');
$result = $auth->authenticate ( $authAdapter );
$data->role = '20';
$auth->getStorage()->write($data);
$this->_redirect('/default/dashboard');
```

after redirect:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance ();
print_r($auth);
```

---

display blank nothing show
please help...

if i use exit after that
after redirect:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance ();
print_r($auth);
exit;
```

then nothing to show other ways redirect back to login page...

Comment: 'Blank page' means there was an error. Check your web server's error log

Comment: I guess you are getting a `fatal error : Trying to get property on a non-object`  due to this statement `$data->role = '20';` I don't see any `$data` object initialisation in your code snippet. Do you confirm this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Login**

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

if(!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable ();
    $authAdapter->setIdentity ('Sameer');
    $result = $auth->authenticate ( $authAdapter );

    if($result->isValid()) {
        //get the found identity
        $identity = $result->getIdentity();

        //$data->role = '20';
        $auth->getStorage()->write($identity);

        $this->_redirect('/default/dashboard');
    }
    else {
        $error = $result->getMessage();
        die($error);
    }
}
else {
    //already logged in
    $this->_redirect('/default/dashboard');
}
```

To get better debug data, add this lines to the beginning of your **index.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```